# Smalltalk Vandermonde-matrix

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

Long in short it is a Vandermonde matrix and I have a problem to run a for in the second dimension of the array.

```
'add meg M-et majd N-et (enter kozotte)(az 1. sor az 1-es szam hatvanyai)' displayNl.
M := stdin nextLine asInteger.
N := stdin nextLine asInteger.
|tomb|
tomb := Array new: M.
x := 1.
y := 1.
a := M + 1.
b := N + 1.
x to: a do: [ :i|
  tomb at:x put: (Array new: N) y to: b do: [ :j |
    x at: y put: (x raisedTo: y - 1) ] ].
tomb printNl.
```

Comment: Isn't there a point missing between `(Array new:N)` and `y to: b do:`? Without point, it looks like these two sentences are going to be interpreted as a single keyword message at:put:to:do:

Comment: Also, `x at: y put: ...` can't work since `x` is an integer. That should probably be `tomb at: y put: ...`. And another thing: `x` and `y` don't change, so raising them to anything will always answer `1` (1^n = 1).

Comment: I don't understand what the code intends. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix, you should start with a vector of alphas, and then calculate each element at i, j as the alpha of that row, raised to column - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good way to create a matrix for which we have an expression of the generic entry `aij`:

```
Matrix class >> fromBlock: aBlock rows: n columns: m
  | matrix |
  matrix := self rows: n columns: m.
  matrix indicesDo: [:i :j | | aij |
    aij := aBlock value: i value: j.
    matrix at: i at: j put: aij].
  ^matrix
```

With the above method you can now implement

```
Matrix class >> vandermonde: anArray degree: anInteger
  ^self
    fromBlock: [:i :j | (anArray at: i) raisedTo: j - 1]
    rows: anArray size
    columns: anInteger + 1
```

**EDIT**

I just realized that in Pharo there is a way to create a matrix from the expression of its `aij`, it is named `rows:columns:tabulate:`, so my answer reduces to:

```
Matrix class >> vandermonde: anArray degree: anInteger
  ^self
    rows: anArray size
    columns: anInteger + 1
    tabulate: [:i :j | (anArray at: i) raisedTo: j - 1]
```